Interpreting the meaning of residual vs. predicted quantile plots in DHARMa?
These are the DHARMa residuals for a logistic regression fitted with glm. From this graph I seem understand that no quantile deviations/issues seem to be detected, but I was not able to determine if there is a cause for concern (seemingly so) for the model predictions all being above .6 on the x-axis. What issues/predictive assumptions would tend to cause these issues?


Hi @WVtinker, welcome to Cross Validated! Could you please post some more information on your model? some useful things would be a summary, a description of what you're modelling (e.g study design), and a head or str of the data, maybe some descriptions of the variables and what values they take too. It's hard to say anything from just the plots
